# Gson: illegalStateExcetpion: expected an int but NAME at line 1 column 3

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to define my own serialize and deserialize methods for `Student` class, so I extended `TypeAdapter` and override its methods, but now deserialization does not work. Why this happens?

```
public class GSONFormat {

@Test
public void run()
{
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, new StudentAdapter());
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    Student s = new Student();
    s.setAge(11);
    s.setName("hiway");
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(s));
    String str = "{\"age\":11,\"name\":\"hiway\"}";
    s = gson.fromJson(str, Student.class);
    System.out.println(s);
}
}

class Student{
    private int age;
    private String name;
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class StudentAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Student>
{

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Student s) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("age");
        out.value(s.getAge());
        out.name("name");
        out.value(s.getName());
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Student read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        in.beginObject();
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setAge(in.nextInt());
        s.setName(in.nextString());
        in.endObject();
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really not how you use `JsonReader`, which is a fairly low-level JSON API. It gives you a stream of individual tokens. I suggest you carefully read [the examples under "Parsing JSON" in the JavaDoc.](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt Ball commented is not a good idea at all writing your type adapter if you do not have a very good reason at all. If you remove this line:

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, new StudentAdapter());
```

your parsing will work without any effort. However you might be interested in understand a bit further what you can do with type adapter. So I give you a possible implementation. Keep in mind that if your class `Student` get more complex, writing your own type adapter can be hard. It's better to let Gson do its own work. Anycase, here is something that patches your code (compiles under Java7, if you use lower version, change `switch` with an `if` chain).

```
class StudentAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Student>
{

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Student s) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("age");
        out.value(s.getAge());
        out.name("name");
        out.value(s.getName());
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Student read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
          }


        in.beginObject();
        Student s = new Student();
        while (in.peek() == JsonToken.NAME){
            String str = in.nextName();
            fillField(in, s, str);
        }


        in.endObject();
        return s;
    }

    private void fillField(JsonReader in, Student s, String str)
            throws IOException {
        switch(str){
            case "age": s.setAge(in.nextInt());
            break;
            case "name": s.setName(in.nextString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```